# OOP design for conditional event processing queue

Tags: design, object-oriented

This will be in C++11, but the object design should be rather agnostic.

I have 3 interface classes, `IEvent`, `ICondition`, `IRunnable`.

The main loop processes multiple kinds of `IEvent`, ranging from "an Application has launched" to "User clicked position (x,y)". Then for each type of event, a list of `ICondition`are notified through a listener interface. For example, `ConditionUserClickedPos` implements `IEventClickListener::onClick(int x, int y)`, which is called by the main loop.

If the position is within the conditions, one or more `IRunnable` objects are called  through `IRunnable::execute(IEvent triggeringEvent)`, like `class RunnableDrawCircleAtClickPosition` and `class RunnableShowPrettyWindow`.

My problem is as follow :

Within `IRunnable::execute(IEvent triggeringEvent)` implementation, I need to get the precise information of the event, but I don't know the exact class hierarchy of the triggeringEvent.

This can be easily solved with dynamic_cast, checking typeid or other reflective oop methods, but those usually breed rather smelly code. I'm also trying to keep the code extendable for new and unrelated events, conditions and runnables that I don't know about yet.

I could also declare a bunch of overloads for `::execute(...)` based on children class types, but this doesn't seem right either.

Is there a silver bullet that I've missed here?

Comment: I'm no expert on these systems, but I always liked [SFML's approach of using a simple union](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-events.php) without any classes or inheritance. An `if(event.type === ...)` is much more palatable than a `std::dynamic_cast`, at least for me.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to write up a complete answer, but I will ask if you are familiar with [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). It is a powerful tool for abstracting away these type checks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Snowman. Inversion of control is precisely what I'm trying to achieve here. At first I thought I would be ok by passing the triggering event down to the IRunnable and letting it be handled in the runnable's implementation. I just don't know how to handle it down the chain. I'll look at the wikipedia article more closely for additional clues.

Comment: @Ixrec : "===", javascript background huh? :p. I could use enumerations to "tag" my class types and check these at runtime. It would save some of the problems caused by dynamic casting, but it still doesn't "feel" like the "right" solution. Also, the SFML approach works by coupling the event dispatch loop with "action" code, like window manipulation and such. The 3rd layer seems to be what creates all the problems.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is below written in PHP pseudocode. So, we have many types of events, all implementing IAbstractEvent interface. When we need to process an event, we give this event to a factory method `FactoryConstructor::constructFactory()`. This method creates abstract factory `AbstractLoopProcessorFactory` descendant for us for processing events of this particular type.

When we have an event which name is `DrawCircle`, factory method creates `DrawCircleLoopProcessorFactory` for us. This factory can create concrete `DrawCirlceConditionProcessor` and `DrawCirlceRunnable` that can work with `IDrawCircleEvent` event.

IDrawCircleEvent interface may have an arbitrary number of methods and arbitrary structure. Only it should extend `IAbstractEvent` to allow our abstract factory to work. So, in DrawCirlceConditionProcessor you already know, that actual event passed to you is `IDrawCircleEvent` and you can reference it as is.

A type cast is probably required because you have to be able to work with an event queue uniformly. But you trade it for logic separation.

```php
interface IAbstractEvent
{
    public function getName();
}

interface IDrawCircleEvent extends IAbstractEvent
{

}

interface IAbstractConditionProcessor
{
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function check(IAbstractEvent $event);
}

interface IDrawCircleConditionProcessor extends IAbstractConditionProcessor
{

}

interface IAbstractRunnable
{
    /**
     * @param IAbstractEvent $event
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function process(IAbstractEvent $event);
}

interface IDrawCircleRunnable extends IAbstractRunnable
{

}

abstract class AbstractLoopProcessorFactory
{
    /**
     * @param IAbstractEvent $event
     *
     * @return IAbstractConditionProcessor
     */
    abstract function getConditionProcessor(IAbstractEvent $event);

    /**
     * @param IAbstractEvent $event
     *
     * @return IAbstractRunnable
     */
    abstract function getRunnable(IAbstractEvent $event);
}

class DrawCircleLoopProcessorFactory extends AbstractLoopProcessorFactory
{
    public function getConditionProcessor(IAbstractEvent $event)
    {
        return new DrawCirlceConditionProcessor($event);
    }

    public function getRunnable(IAbstractEvent $event)
    {
        return new DrawCirlceRunnable($event);
    }
}

class FactoryConstructor
{
    /**
     * @param IAbstractEvent $event
     *
     * @return AbstractLoopProcessorFactory
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static function constructFactory(IAbstractEvent $event)
    {
        switch ($event->getName()) {
            case "DrawCircle":
                return new DrawCircleLoopProcessorFactory();
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown event name {$event->getName()}");
        }
    }
}

class Application
{
    public static function main()
    {
        /**
         * @var IAbstractEvent[]
         */
        $eventList = [];

        foreach ($eventList as $event) {
            $factory = FactoryConstructor::constructFactory($event);
            $conditionChecker = $factory->getConditionProcessor();
            if ($conditionChecker->check($event)) {
                $runnable = $factory->getRunnable($event);
                $runnable->process($event);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So the idea is to centralize the reflection in an abstract factory, then the concrete factories will know enough about the types they handle to avoid further manual casting. This is certainly better than having each event handle their own dynamic casting. I'll see how this can work for me.

Comment: @Eric Yep. After you make decision, tell me the results if possible, please.

Comment: I ran into some problems with this approach. In my design, the conditions depends on the events and not the other way around. The events should have no knowledge of what may happen when they are raised. Maybe my formulation of the problem wasn't clear enough, or I don't understand your implementation correctly. The constructFactory() call implies that the event know about "DrawCircle" before conditions are checked, while I was trying to have the "DrawCircle" decision taken based on the conditions.

Comment: Also I am not sure that it truly solve my problem. In process(), how can I get the event (x,y) position from IAbstractEvent? How can a different runnable get "Application name which just launched" from IAbstractEvent as well? This will most probably involve some dynamic casting and runtime type checking.

Comment: @Eric I will post some clarifications to my approach tonight.

Comment: @Eric Posted some text :)